# Mongodb sort when a field value correspond

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my problem is a bit tricky.
Here is an example of 3 "types" of elements that my database can give me:

First one :

```
{ 
_id: 1234,
informations: {
    ...
},
data_fields: [
    {
        name: "input",
        value: "loremipsum"
    },
    {
        fieldset_name: "label",
        value: "loremipsum"
    }
]
}
```

Second One :

```
{ 
_id: 2451,
informations: {
    ...
},
data_fields: [
    {
        name: "number",
        value: "loremipsum"
    },
    {
        fieldset_name: "input",
        value: "loremipsum"
    },
    {
        fieldset_name: "button",
        value: "loremipsum",
        fieldset_data: [
            [
                {
                    fieldset.name: "home",
                    fieldset.value: "loremipsum" 
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
]
}
```

Third one :

```
{ 
_id: 4561,
informations: {
    ...
},
data_fields: [
    {
        fieldset_name: "button",
        value: "loremipsum",
        fieldset_data: [
            [
                {
                    fieldset.name: "input",
                    fieldset.value: "loremipsum" 
                },
                {
                    fieldset.name: "label",
                    fieldset.value: "loremipsum" 
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    fieldset.name: "home",
                    fieldset.value: "loremipsum" 
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
]
}
```

In this example, let's say I want to check if there is an **input**.

As you can see, there are different places I need to check:
In all **data_fields** with **name**, again but with **fieldset_name** and in each **fieldset_data** if they exist in the **data_fields**.

And I want that if there is at least one **input**, it gives my element a **element** field.

So my result would be for example :

```
{ 
_id: 1234,
informations: {
    ...
},
data_fields: [
    {
        name: "input",
        value: "loremipsum"
    },
    {
        fieldset_name: "label",
        value: "loremipsum"
    }
],
element: "input"
}
```

Actually, I have done an aggregate and that :

```
{ $addFields: {
    element: { $map: {
        input: "$data_fields",
        as: "data_field",
        in: { $cond: {
            if: { $eq: ["$$data_field.name", "input"] },
            then: "$$data_field.name",
            else: { $cond: {
                if: { $eq: ["$$data_field.fieldset_name", "input"] },
                then: "$$data_field.fieldset_name",
                else: { $map: {
                    input: "$$data_field.fieldset_data",
                    as: "fieldsets",
                    in : { $map: {
                        input: "$$fieldsets",
                        as: "fieldset",
                        in: { $cond: {
                            if: { $eq: ["$$fieldset.name", "input"] },
                            then:  "$$fieldset.name",
                            else: "$$REMOVE"
                         }}
                    }}
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
```

but the result look like that :

```
{ 
_id: 1234,
informations: {
    ...
},
data_fields: [
    {
        name: "input",
        value: "loremipsum"
    },
    {
        fieldset_name: "label",
        value: "loremipsum"
    }
],
element: [null, "input", [null, null, null], null]
}
```

Comment: I see you are using field names with a dot (`.`) embedded in it - `e.g., fieldset.name`. As of MongoDB version 5.0  you can access such fields using the aggregate operator [$getField](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/).

Comment: Unfortunately the project I am working on is in version 3.7.
I can't update it or change anything of that kind. :c